# Are scientists biased towards the government's influence?

Tags: politics

A common rebuttal to scientific studies is that most scientists are funded by the government, and hence are working to a government's agenda. Sometimes the claim extends to suggest that the peer-review process is biased towards the government's opinion.

This is most common for political topics, such as Evolution or AGW.

Is there any evidence that some notable research has been biased in the findings or peer review due to government influence?

Comment: I think this question would be better with some concrete examples. It is probably region-specific (see [Lysenkoism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysenkoism)\). But AGW is probably a poor example. Do you need to go very far back before you find that neither big party had a policy on it? Yet, the scientific view hasn't flip-flopped.

Comment: What you are basically asking is whether the government of the day inserts Bias into Scientific Research.

As Oddthinking said - it may be better to pick one specific area and ask about that, otherwise it is a bit too broad a question.

Comment: Are you asking about Policy-based evidence making? - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_evidence_making

Comment: My salary is paid by the government, and so are most of my lab expenses. That in no way implies that the government tells me what I have to do or how to interpret my results.

Comment: I think there is a more interesting question lurking in here obscured by the point about government. The interesting question is whether the scientific quality of what gets published goes down when there is a consensus (government supporting or not) on a topic among the funders of research. There has been a lot of shoddy work published about the ozone hole, global warming and the health effects of smoking since a near-consensus was reached on those topics. Scientists are biased by what topics will get grants and publications.

Comment: @matt_black have you any details of this 'shoddy work'?

Comment: @Dropjaw The best example is James Lovelock's comment on the science of the Ozone hole (and his related criticism of what was happening in climate science) reported here: [guardian interview](http://www.guardian.co.uk/environment/blog/2010/mar/29/james-lovelock)

Comment: @nico - it's not necessarily a qiestion of the government telling you what to do. It's a question of (1) do you have a conscious **or unconsious** bias towards preferring the results that keep you funded (as a random made up example, if AGW was scientifically shown to be untrue, a vast majority of AGW researchers would find themselves severely short on funding/jobs)....

Comment: @nico - ... (2) Do you as a scientist have a (again possibly unconscious) bias towards big/strong government telling people what to do - of course, based on your undoubtedly superior advice - which is a reasonably accurate approximation of thinking of people starting as far back as French Revolution, before you start reacting to this as a modern political claim.

Comment: @nico - and before you exclaim that scientists would NEVER tolerate such thing, read Oddthinking's link to Lysenko. There is a reason why a vast majority of scientifically-educated immigrants from USSR as **significantly** more skeptical of AGW than the similar demographics in USA - they know first hand how much impact politics can have - and has - on science.

Comment: @DVK: you cannot take Lysenko as an example of ALL scientists. Lysenko was not even paid by the Russian government before he started promising impossible things: he exploited their gullibility to gain power. A scientist could be biased towards or against the government independently of the fact that he is paid by them. To be honest, in my area of research I do not even see how could I be biased towards the governmental view, as there is none...

Comment: @DVK: *do you have a conscious or unconsious bias towards preferring the results that keep you funded* is also irrelevant, as it is a remark applicable to any source of funding, public or private.

Comment: @nico - it's very relevant to branches of science where most funding comes from the government (AGW)

Comment: @DVK: I am sorry, but the question starts with: "A common rebuttal **to scientific studies** is that **most scientists** are funded by the government". Unless you are saying that the majority of scientists study global warming or evolution (which is plain false) I would say that the claim is a very unfair generalization. The claim goes on saying that "the peer-review process is biased towards the government's opinion". I am not denying that it can happen in certain branches of science, but I do not agree on the fact that it is the norm in science in general.

Comment: @nico - no argument. Many (if not most) scientific studies have no political impact and therefore the results of the study would not impact the funding (in other words, there is no "government agenda" to the study results). But the second paragraph specifically singles out AGW (I'm not aware of any  government-funded evolution studies designed to prove or disprove evolution)

Comment: I would add drug policy to candidates for corruption. For example it sounds like the theory that pot is a gateway drug was swallowed whole and regurgitated by that research community with no critical examination. Maybe I/we should make a question about that. Not only is that research field blatantly political (funded by ONDCP), but it is also a very fuzzy sort of science where it is very hard (if not impossible) to confidently answer the questions that the funders want answered.

Comment: There's papers that look at whether corporate funding influences paper results, so this should be an answerable question.

Comment: In a different view: When the scientific community prefers theory X over theory Y and governments also prefer theory X over theory Y, this may be a sign of governments acting reasonably at least once.

Comment: Notably, I think the question should be: is there evidence that science is systematically biased in favor of outcomes agreeing with government preferences? Because there are certainly many individual cases of government influence, and also many of non-government (e.g. private industry) influence.

Comment: Neither evolution or AGW are political issues.  The first is a scientific fact, the second is an extrapolation based on observed temperature data trends.

Comment: I'm amazed that the answers on this question (including mine) have been voted for in the way they have (and without particular reference as to why the down votes). The most upvoted answer is an uncritical paean to the independence of climate science against government influence. This isn't about climate science guys! Nor is it about whether government is all powerful. It is just about whether government can influence the content of science to some extent.

Comment: @matt_black   Clarity is important.  Anyone who creates a poll knows that by changing 1 word in a question that can greatly influence the response.   The title of this question is "Are scientists biased towards the government's influence".  The question is NOT what you suggest, "can government influence science".   I would say that scientists are, if anything, bias against government sway, so the answer to the first question is no - scientists don't obey the government, they're closer (en mass) to libertarians in principal, but yes, government can certainly sway science and some individuals.

Comment: @userLTK So how do you measure bias except in relation to the actual science that gets done? I don't care what scientists believe; what matters is what they do and there are examples here that show government having a malign influence. Besides, even if scientists are uniquely virtuous, the way they will fight bias is to recognise that it exists rather than to pretend it doesn't.

Comment: @matt_black  "So how do you measure bias except in relation to the actual science that gets done?" . . . that's the million dollar question and one that can't possibly be answered in 500 characters.   I may try to give an answer to this, but it's an enormously broad question and made difficult cause scientists are individuals, not a collective.   I also didn't say anyting close to scientists are uniquely virtuas I said, en mass, they're closer to libertarians - who in and of themselves aren't virtuous, they just want to be left alone - no real virtue in that.

Comment: @matt_black  I also never said that pretending bias doesn't exist is the way to go - that's moronic.  You need to actually read what I wrote cause your responding to things I didn't write. . . . If I have time, I'll draft a longer answer to this question, but I worked on an outline, and there's no easy way to do it because the question covers so much ground.   An entire novel could be written on the history of government vs science and the effects there-in and a discussion of bias in science, issues, fixes, peer review and the scientific method.  That's long too.  I might try, I might not.

Comment: The problem with the question is that the idea that bias exists in *some* government sponsored science doesn't lead to the general idea that is is reasonable to dismiss studies because the government paid for them. Science should be judged on its quality and content not on who pays for it. That doesn't mean that some bias doesn't exist which everyone should be aware of, but it doesn't mean we can generalise and dismiss everything. Nor the opposite where we tell stories of heroic scientific resistance to bias. we need to recognise it exists to fight it.

Comment: @matt_black, You're half right, half wrong.   Yes, science should be judged on it's quality and content.   I couldn't agree with that more.   But, by judging science on it's quality and content, bias becomes irrelevant.   Einstein was bias against quantum physics, for all the good it did him.   Quantum physics was still right.  The pursuit of truth eliminates bias because bias doesn't change the science.   It's what Feynman said  "you can't fool nature".   You can't change the truth with bias, so by seeking the truth, bias is eliminated.

Comment: I think the question needs several qualifications. Scientists in places like Saudi Arabia or even China are under different pressures from the government that ones from other countries.

Comment: @userLTK True in the big stuff. But a lot of areas of dispute have large grey areas where the facts are not 100% clear as they are with, say, most quantum mechanics. Does breast cancer screening work? Grey area, lots of opportunity for bias in results.

Comment: @matt_black Breast Cancer screenings, while imperfect, improve the chance of catching cancer early which is great.  There's also a lot of false positives in the testing - which is bad.   Also, the entire medical service industry is a jumble of convenience, habit, cost effectiveness, old equipment that's expensive to upgrade and profit.   To use breast cancer screenings as an example of science is weird because it's also an example of corporate profit and compromise.   If breast cancer screenings was left entirely up to science, it would look hugely different (and it would cost more)

Comment: @matt_black and your quantum mechanics argument seems completely misplaced.  Not knowing something isn't bias.   Quantum mechanics is one of the most pure areas of scientific research today.  Methods and results are publicly available.    A grey area as to what we know/don't know and a grey area as to bias are entirely separate things.

Answer (score 18):

From 2001 to early 2009, the US was governed by an administration which frequently got involved in climate science.

When an oil company demanded that climate scientists working on the IPCC and the United States' own National Assessment [be removed](http://web.archive.org/web/20100120095525/http://www.rollingstone.com/politics/story/15148655/the_secret_campaign_of_president_bushs_administration_to_deny_global_warming/3):

> Exxon's wish was the CEQ's command. According to an internal e-mail obtained by Rolling Stone, Connaughton's first order of business - even before his nomination was made public - was to write his White House colleagues-to-be from his law firm of Sidley & Austin. He echoed Exxon's call that Bierbaum, the acting director of the Office of Science and Technology Policy, be "dealt." In the end, each of the scientists on Exxon's hit list was replaced. "It was clear there was a strong lobby and activity against me by some in the energy industry - especially ExxonMobil," says Watson.

The Bush administration then appointed industry lobbyists to head the White House's Council on Environmental Quality. They [edited scientific reports](http://web.archive.org/web/20080117172136/http://www.rollingstone.com/politics/story/15148655/the_secret_campaign_of_president_bushs_administration_to_deny_global_warming/5) being put out by scientists working in the administration to undermine their conclusions:

> On the opening page of the chapter on climate impacts, Cooney inserted a litany of language in bold intended to cast doubt on the science: "the weakest links in our knowledge . . . a lack of understanding . . . uncertainties . . . considerable uncertainty . . . perhaps even greater uncertainty . . . regarded as tentative."

And after it turned out that those modifications weren't enough:

> "We tried to put some qualifiers on that chapter in the report," Cooney told him. "We'd take the text from EPA, and then we'd add a sentence like, 'We don't really know if this is really happening.' So we tried to do it, but I can see now that we made a total mess of it."

After that, Cooney was then given [veto power](http://web.archive.org/web/20080103183638/http://www.rollingstone.com/politics/story/15148655/the_secret_campaign_of_president_bushs_administration_to_deny_global_warming/6) over scientists working within the administration:

> From then on, Cooney wielded a heavier pen when editing official reports on global warming. Not content to obscure science with uncertainty, he began to rewrite the science itself. Draft documents made public by the House Oversight Committee reveal that Cooney now had veto power over federal scientists, including Richard Moss, coordinator of the Climate Change Science Program Office, and even James Mahoney, the assistant commerce secretary nominally in charge of America's climate science.

The Council on Environmental Quality also controlled which administration scientists would be able to [speak to the media](http://www.csmonitor.com/2007/1212/p03s03-uspo.html), and edited the statements they made:

> Dr. Karl, it says, "was not allowed to comment in his written testimony that 'modern climate change is dominated by human influences,' that 'we are venturing into the unknown territory with changes in climate,' or that 'it is very likely (>95 percent probability) that humans are largely responsible for many of the observed changes in climate.' " Instead of saying that global warming "is playing" a role in increased hurricane intensity, his comment became "may play" a role.

However, in the midst of all this, the scientific community made statements that contradicted the White House position. For example, in 2006 the world's largest general scientific society, the American Association for the Advancement of Science, put out [a statement](http://www.aaas.org/news/press_room/climate_change/mtg_200702/aaas_climate_statement.pdf) saying:

> The scientific evidence is clear: global climate change caused by human activities is occurring now, and it is a growing threat to society. Accumulating data from across the globe reveal a wide array of effects: rapidly melting glaciers, destabilization of major ice sheets, increases in extreme weather, rising sea level, shifts in species ranges, and more. The pace of change and the evidence of harm have increased markedly over the last five years.

In 2005 the Joint Science Academies, a group of 11 national scientific societies, including the US National Academy of Sciences, [stated that](http://nationalacademies.org/onpi/06072005.pdf):

> There will always be uncertainty in understanding a system as complex as the world’s climate. However there is now strong evidence that significant global warming is occurring. The evidence comes from direct measurements of rising surface air temperatures and subsurface ocean temperatures and from phenomena such as increases in
> average global sea levels, retreating glaciers, and changes to many physical and biological systems. It is likely that most of the warming in recent decades can be attributed to human activities (IPCC 2001). This warming has already led to changes in the Earth's climate.

In 2003 the American Geophysical Union [stated that](http://www.aip.org/fyi/2004/042.html):

> Human activities are increasingly altering the Earth's climate. These effects add to natural influences that have been present over Earth's history. Scientific evidence strongly indicates that natural influences cannot explain the rapid increase in global near-surface temperatures observed during the second half of the 20th century.

---

An article in the New York Times gives many examples of several administrations attempting to [prevent the Surgeon-General from issuing statements on politically sensitive topics](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/07/11/washington/11surgeon.html?_r=2):

> Dr. Koop, said he had been discouraged by top officials in the Reagan administration from discussing the AIDS crisis. He did so anyway.
>
> Dr. Satcher said that the Clinton administration discouraged him from issuing a report showing that needle-exchange programs were effective in reducing disease. He released the report anyway.
>
> Former Surgeon General Richard H. Carmona told a Congressional panel Tuesday that top Bush administration officials repeatedly tried to weaken or suppress important public health reports because of political considerations. The administration, Dr. Carmona said, would not allow him to speak or issue reports about stem cells, emergency contraception, sex education, or prison, mental and global health issues. Top officials delayed for years and tried to “water down” a landmark report on secondhand smoke, he said. Released last year, the report concluded that even brief exposure to cigarette smoke could cause immediate harm.
>
> Dr. Carmona described being invited to testify at the government’s nine-month racketeering trial of the tobacco industry that ended in 2005. He said top administration officials discouraged him from testifying while simultaneously telling the lead government lawyer in the case that he was not competent to testify. Dr. Carmona testified anyway.

---

Probably the most famous example of political interference in science is, of course, Lysenkoism in Soviet Russia, described in Martin Gardner's [Fads and Fallacies in the Name of Science](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=TwP3SGAUsnkC&pg=PA140) [copied by hand, blame me for any typos]:

> Seldom before in the history of modern science has a crackpot achieved the eminence, adulation and power achieved by Trofim D. Lysenko, the Soviet Union's leading authority on evolution and heredity. Not only have his opinions been pronounced dogma by the Kremlin, but his Russian opponents (whose views are held everywhere but in the USSR) in recent years have been systematically eliminated from their posts. Some have died in prison camps. Some have simply vanished. A few remain at work - but it is work in other fields of biology...
>
> A host of experiments have been designed to test Lamarckianism. All that have been verified have proved negative. On the other hand, tens of thousands of experiments - reported in journals and carefully checked and rechecked by genticists throughout the world - have established the correctness of the gene-mutation theory beyond all reasonable doubt...
>
> Just as Lamarckianism combines easily with an idealism in which the entire creation is fulfilling God's vast plan by constant upward striving, so also does it combine easily with political doctines which emphasize the building of a better world...
>
> "In 1933 or thereabouts," [Muller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.J._Muller) wrote, "the geneticists Chetverikoff, Ferry, and Ephroimson were all, on separate occasions, banished to Sibera, and Levitsky to a labor camp in the European Arctic... in 1936, the Communist geneticist Agol was convicted of 'Menshevik idealism' in genetics... Certain it is, however, that from 1936 on Soviet geneticists of all ranks lived a life a terror. Most of them who were not imprisoned, banished, or executed were forced to enter other lines of work.

In an expression of grim humour, Tony Judt observed in "A History of Europe Since 1945":

> Stalin left his nuclear physicists alone... [He] may well have been mad but he was not stupid.

Whilst the Soviet government was able to use coercive pressure on scientists within the Soviet Union, Lysenkoism never caught on outside the reach of the Soviet bloc, and eventually collapsed even within it.

---

These are just a few examples - clearly politicians (on both sides of politics) do frequently attempt to interfere with science - ranging from outright oppression to limiting speech or editing reports - where the scientific results went against their political positions. However, it does seem that again and again the independent, international scientific community has been robust to government interference and influence.

In the US, the Climate Action Report, was still largely seen as in support of climate science in spite of the bits where extra uncertainty was edited in for political reasons. The Surgeons-General were still able to publish health warnings even when the government were able to oppose it. And the ultimate judge will be the independent scientific community, who continued to strongly support climate science even when the government of the day was trying to edit it out.

Comment: Yay for scientists! Boo for politicians. But does this answer the question? Is there evidence that scientists themselves do or don't publish papers that follow party lines?

Comment: That would be difficult to pick out, in science there's going to be a lot of back-and-forth and legitimate disagreement on politically sensitive topics as well as insensitive ones. And I certainly think that there are going to be individual scientists who are politically biased. But the general scope of the question seemed to me to be about whether the scientific process and consensus-building were robust to political interference, so I tried to address that.

Comment: That's a bit like saying that the US government has no ability to influence the US supreme court. For short time frame that's true. Over long time frames the government can however elect the judges that it needs to get the court judgements it wants. A lot of scientists have tenure that's similar to US supreme court judges. When it comes to people claiming that the government pushes AGW, they are talking about longer timeframes.

Comment: Though there might be isolated incidents like these, and more ([link]http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=north-carolina-sea-level-rises-desipte-senators) - one would expect overall research results to shift with some kind of pattern coinciding with shifts in government. I still say that this is something we do not see.

Comment: Evolution is a prime example here, scientific consensus here has always been 100% in the same direction regardless of all the political wrangling that goes on, especially in the US where views are so divided on this subject.

Comment: Rolling Stone isn't a very reliable source. It's a very popular magazine for AIDS denialists and other kind of conspiracy theories. (Declaration of interest: my day job involves HIV research).

Comment: You are writing "from 2001 to early 2009, the US was governed by an administration which frequently got involved in climate science". What about after 2009? Did the stance of the government regarding scientific influence change in general or only in regards to global warming?

Comment: So, sometimes politicians try to interfere: are you arguing that they don't succeed? I'm not sure the examples show that or the opposite with any clarity.

Comment: Brilliant answer.   I especially like the bit about Stalin, as climate change tends to get so much attention these days.   There are probably several interesting examples of science vs ruling powers over the last several decades or hundred years.

Answer (score 3):

> Are scientists biased towards the government's influence?

When a notable research has been biased due to some external influence.  The is referred to as *[Research Bias](https://explorable.com/research-bias)* or *[Experimental Bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer-expectancy_effect)*:

> Research bias, also called experimenter bias, is a process where the scientists performing the research influence the results, in order to portray a certain outcome.

#### There is evidence that Non-Government Research Bias exists

For example, drug research that is sponsored by the pharmaceutical industry, developer and producer of pharmaceuticals, is more likely to end up favoring the drug under consideration than studies sponsored by government grants or charitable organizations;[evidence suggests](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12928469)  <sup>(1)</sup> .

#### So, what about Government Research Bias?

Cato Institute, public policy research organization, that "[accepts no government funding](http://www.cato.org/about)" states in a [published paper](http://object.cato.org/sites/cato.org/files/pubs/pdf/working-paper-29.pdf)  <sup>(2)</sup>  fifteen specific practices of bias in the context of funded scientific research:

> 1. **Funding agency programs** that have a biased focus.
> 2. Agency Strategic Plans, RFPs, etc., **with an agenda, not asking the right questions**.
> 3. **Biased peer review** of research proposals.
> 4. **Biased selection of research proposals** by the agency program.
> 5. **Preference for modeling** using biased assumptions.
> 6. **Biased peer review** of journal articles and conference presentations.
> 7. **Biased meta-analysis** of the scientific literature.
> 8. **Failure to report** negative results.
> 9. **Manipulation of data** to bias results.
> 10. **Refusing to share** data with potential critics.
> 11. Asserting **conjectures as facts**.
> 12. **False confidence** in tentative findings.
> 13. **Exaggeration of the importance** of findings by researchers and agencies.
> 14. **Amplification of exaggeration** by the press.
> 15. **More funding with an agenda**, building on the above, so the cycle repeats and builds

The study documents search terms for Google Scholar for each practice of bias that might be related to the government, example:

> 2. Agency Strategic Plans, RFPs, etc., with an agenda, not asking the right questions.
>
> **Concept Analysis:** Research proposals may be shaped by agency Strategic Plans and Requests for Proposals (RFP's), also called Funding Opportunity Announcements (FOA's). These documents often specify those scientific questions that the agency deems important, hence worthy of funding. Thus the resulting research proposals may be biased, speaking to what the
>   agency claims is important rather than what the researcher thinks
>
> **Literature Snapshot:** There appears to be very little research on this type of bias. A search on Google Scholar for the occurrence of the three terms "**Federal**" and "**research**" and "bias" in article titles for the period 2010-2014 **gives zero hits**! Full text search for these three common words returns over 62,000 items but only a few are even looking at bias, such as gender bias. The occurrence of all three words somewhere in an article is probably mostly just a coincidental combination.
>
> **Search for "research" and "bias" in titles gives 371 hits, but only a few of the articles are even related to federal funding. Most are looking at statistical analysis issues, such as sample selection.**

And so on...

The study concludes that government funding has "received little" attention and has not been studied well; in other words the study didn't find any worthy empirical data regarding government funding and bias:

> The role of government funding in inducing policy-driven bias seems **to have received
>   very little attention**, even though it may be widespread. There are certain exceptions,
>   most noticeably in the climate change debate and environmental policy in general. But
>   here the attention is more a matter of public concern than one of quantitative scientific
>   research. [...]
>
> The notion of cascading systemic bias, induced by government funding, does not appear
>   to have been much studied.

To dig deeper, some studies suggest that the question of bias of a research might be [opinion-based](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1126323/):

> It is important to remember that **interpretation of data is inevitably subjective** and can itself result in bias.

Conclusion: Apparently, there is little-to-no evidence regarding government research bias, cato.org reports. [Governments got accused of crime research bias in the past](http://www.research-live.com/news/government-accused-of-crime-research-bias/3001634.article), and [professors wrote books accusing federal governments of having biased peer review systems since 1950](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521643155), while other professors and notable scientists argue that the interpretation of data is inevitably subjective  <sup>(3)</sup> :

> Doctors are being encouraged to improve their critical appraisal skills to make better use of medical research. But when using these skills, it is important to remember that interpretation of data is inevitably subjective and can itself result in bias.

As skeptics, all we say is: "We don't really know".

---

<sup>(1) Als-nielson, B., W. Chen, C. Gluud, and L.L. Kjaergard. 2003. [Association of funding and conclusions in randomized drug trials: A reflection of treatment effect or adverse events?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12928469) Journal of the American Medical Association 290:921-928.</sup>

<sup>(2) [Is the Government Buying Science or Support? A Framework Analysis of Federal Funding-induced Biases By David E. Wojick and Patrick J. Michaels](http://object.cato.org/sites/cato.org/files/pubs/pdf/working-paper-29.pdf) April 30, 2015 CATO WORKING PAPER No. 29</sup>

<sup>(3) [Kaptchuk TJ. Effect of interpretive bias on research evidence. BMJ : British Medical Journal.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1126323/#ref21) 2003;326(7404):1453-1455.</sup>

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that research bias strongly depends on who is trying to influence it. Both government and non-government organizations have their own agenda, and there is no reason to believe that one is much different from another.

Comment: The CATO institute may not receive any government money but they receive a TON of special interest money.   It's hard to think of a source that I would trust less than the CATO institute.  Their mission statement is to provide statistical bias with consistant conservative lean .   Nothing they've ever printed has ever been neutral and nothing they say means anything.    If the IPCC was operated under the same principals as the CATO institute operates, I'd agree with the republicans on Climate change.

Comment: I have no control over what you believe, Cato's funding is publicly available.  Their biggest funders are the Koch brothers who are highly political and strongly conservative and their studies consistently land on the side of their funders.   http://www.debate.org/debates/The-Cato-Institute-does-not-deserve-respect-or-credibility/1/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cato_Institute  They also make right wing watch lists, which you don't make unless you're - you know, right wing.   http://www.rightwingwatch.org/content/cato-institute   I can give you lots more if you want.

Comment: OK, I can live with automation.    I'll delete my comment if you like.  (Cato's still hugely partisan though - it's their purpose.  They're a Koch Brothers tool.) /// rant rant rant.

Answer (score 2):

Per framework analysis by David E. Wojick and Patrick J. Michaels in April [2015](http://object.cato.org/sites/cato.org/files/pubs/pdf/working-paper-29.pdf), "the investigation of potential federally induced bias is not an active research area. There appears to be a major gap in bias research." The main example provided for government bias in the CATO working paper is regarding numerous allegations of bias linking federal policies on climate change and federal funding of climate research.

> Conclusions and Observations: What we have found, as explained in this report, is that some types of bias are being studied extensively and quantitatively. Various aspects of peer review and publication bias, especially in biomedicine, appear to be the most heavily researched types of bias.
>
> The role of funding in inducing bias is frequently alluded to as a potential financial
> conflict of interest. But it is not the focus of most research, which tends to look more at
> the practice of bias than at its cause. A new research thrust is likely needed.

Comment: The CATO institute is built on bias.   Any conclusions they reach means very little.   They get paid to reach the conclusions their special interests want them to.   They're not neutral on anything.   Scientific Research needs to strive to be neutral.  They clearly strive to make their funders right.

Bias research in and of itself isn't necessary.   Peer review is far more effective.  A researcher can be bias and still be right and a researcher can be neutral and be wrong.   It's the scientific method that needs to be upheld, not scientists' intent.   Cato's wagging the dog.

Comment: @userLTK: At the moment, that sounds like special pleading fallacy, especially with no evidence provided.

Comment: @Oddthinking  It always surprises me when skeptics refuse to be skeptical.   The CATO institute is a special interest backed organization.  This shouldn't be news to anyone.    What do you think a Washington DC based think tank is? . . . now, I hadn't realized this was an old question or I wouldn't have responded so much, it showed up linked to another question, but a DC based think tank is a special interest organization.   That's a statement of fact not fallacy.

Comment: @userLTK: Great. When it is an acceptable answer, flag it, and I will undelete it. When it becomes acceptable to be rude to other users, I will undelete your comment.

Comment: @Oddthinking  Dude, others were rude to me.   I just tried to give answers.   Posters with high reputation too.

Answer (score 2):

**Those who pay the piper call the tune (or at least get some influence on the playlist top 10)**

The question isn't whether government rigidly *controls* what research scientists do but whether government has *influence* on it. And, unless you accept the improbable idea that all government is entirely beneficent and interested only in the truth, that influence creates *bias*. Showing that some scientists disagree with the government agenda doesn’t count as strong evidence against this idea. What needs to be shown is simply that the mix of research that gets done is influenced by what governments want to see. It is the portfolio of research as a whole that is biased if this influence exists not every individual piece of research by every scientist.

To show the potential for government influence it is worth looking at the sources of research funding. To show that bias exists it is worth looking at some research topics where we can see how the influence has changed the portfolio.

But there are several problems is detecting bias and finding its source. Some may arise from *scientists* not because of bias in government intent. Researchers in search of grant money may choose topics likely to be attractive to the grant-awarding bodies because they perceive this will enhance the possibility of getting future grants. Or the grant-awarding decision makers might influence researchers by promising future grants if the results are favourable (nobody has a problem believing this is true for industrial funders of research and the suspicion that it may be true is the reasoner strong disclosure rules around conflict of interest in many journals).

Another issue is that neither government nor science is a uniform, monolithic group. Individuals inside government may pursue a research agenda to influence other parts of government (this biases science even though the whole of the government machine doesn't have a single view). Scientists who have been appointed by government to grant-awarding bodies may pursue personal agendas. Is their appointment a sign of government bias or a personal issue?

**Research Funding**

Governments often fund a large proportion of research conducted within an economy, though this didn’t used to be true and is a legacy of two world wars. A contrarian view of this history is told by [Terence Kealey](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312173067).

In the USA, federal funding is the largest source of money for University R&D with more than $25billion spent per year according to [this 2009 report](http://www.nsf.gov/statistics/infbrief/nsf09318/). The UK spends a lot less (as a much smaller economy and less research intensive) but the government still funds the majority of university R&D and the overwhelming majority of R&D in public research institutions according to [this ONS document](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/rel/rdit1/gross-domestic-expenditure-on-research-and-development/2012/stb-gerd-2012.html#tab-R-D-Expenditure-by-Funding-Sector).

So the preponderance of funding for “independent” research comes from government. We don’t expect industrial R&D to be independent of “bias” as its entire purpose is to pursue the interests of the sponsor.

So does government funding influence the content of that research? It seems obvious that it will unless government if regarded as spectacularly virtuous. But what about specific examples?

**Examples of bias caused by government**

The most obvious example where the agenda of science was not just biased but totally perverted is Lysenkoism in the Soviet Union under Stalin. As [Wikipedia has it](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lysenkoism):

> Ultimately, Lysenkoism failed to deliver on its promises in agricultural yields and even had unfortunate consequences such as the arresting, firing, or execution of 3,000 biologists due to attempts from Lysenko to suppress opposition to his theory, the president of the Agriculture Academy was sent to prison and died there, and overall, scientific research in genetics was effectively destroyed until the death of Stalin in 1953. Due to Lysenkoism, crop yields in the USSR declined as well.

Nobody expects democratic governments to resort to those sorts of methods to drive their agenda. But the funding still can have a strong influence on the research that gets done.

A topical recent example is the congressional ban on funding for research into the statistics or science relating to the use of guns in the USA. The CDC (which would normally have an interest in researching ways of reducing harm from avoidable causes of death) has effectively been prevented from doing so becasue of NRA sponsored Congressional restrictions since 1996 (see this [recent summary at Vox](http://www.vox.com/2015/10/6/9465649/gun-violence-research-cdc)). The general issue has also been addressed on this site in this question: [Did the National Rifle Association (NRA) block research into statistics related to gun control?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15609/did-the-national-rifle-association-nra-block-research-into-statistics-related)

So this is a negative way the agenda influences the portfolio of things that get researched.

But there are more subtle ways conventional and government opinion can influence the mix of research that gets done. An example is the way the harms of passive smoking have been researched. The conventional wisdom is that it must be bad (note that few will now question that smoking kills as the evidence is unusually overwhelming). But whether *passive* smoking is just annoying or seriously damaging to its victims is a lot less clear. Maybe. But it is almost unimaginable that public health authorities would tolerate research that says the effect is unclear. When Enstrom and Kabat [published research](http://www.bmj.com/content/326/7398/1057) pointing out the weak evidence base for the harms of passive smoking in the BMJ they were viciously attacked by the establishment.

The US government tried to prosecute them for their views ([Wikipedia](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/James_Enstrom)):

> In 2006, prosecutors in a federal racketeering case filed documents which stated that Enstrom had received $94,500 from the tobacco industry between 1992 and 1997. The following year, the judge in this case, Gladys Kessler, ruled that major tobacco companies were guilty of racketeering and misleading the public regarding the dangers of second-hand smoke, citing the paper co-authored by Enstrom in the BMJ as evidence of this. 
>   ...
>   In 2010, the University of California, Los Angeles School of Public Health announced that it would not be rehiring Enstrom because it felt his research was "not aligned with the academic mission" of their department. In 2012, Enstrom filed a lawsuit in federal court against UCLA in response to them terminating his position there. In the suit, Enstrom said that UCLA administrators "discriminated against Dr. Enstrom based on his ideological and political affiliations and sought to purge an academic dissenter from their ranks." In 2015, the case was settled, with UCLA allowing Enstrom to use the title "retired researcher" and continue to access university resources.

But Enstrom had always disclosed his funding (and, more importantly, probably could never have expected government funding for research leading to this conclusion). What is remarkable is the degree of irrationality in the original criticism of his paper. As a [summary of the BMJ responses](http://www.bmj.com/content/327/7413/505.1) said:

> Many letters were highly charged and hostile. “It is astounding how much of the criticism springs from Ad Hominem argument rather than from scientific criticism of the study itself,” wrote a “private citizen” from Philadelphia PA. “As a publisher of the leading Austrian medical online news service I feel quite embarrassed following the debate on this article. Many postings look more like a witch hunt than a scientific debate,” wrote another. It got bitter, and at times personal. A great read for anyone who enjoys a scrap. Disappointing for readers looking for a dispassionate appraisal of Enstrom and Kabat's study and its implications.

My point is that the establishment in general and government in particular reacted in a hostile way to contrarian views to the detriment of science. Enstrom’s views may be wrong (and some subsequent evidence suggests it was) but the response was to try and devalue and suppress the results rather than to do better research.

Another example where the government in the UK has tried to influence the research being done relates to policy on illegal drugs. [David Nutt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Nutt) was the chairman of a supposedly independent group, the [Advisory Committee on the Misuse of Drugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advisory_Council_on_the_Misuse_of_Drugs), that was supposed to influence government policy and has a statutory role in drug classification in the UK. Nutt was sacked from his role for publishing work suggesting that some popular drugs were substantially less harmful that the government believed. Many other members of the committee resigned in protest at this political interference.

Nutt has subsequently argued that government policy (especially the desire to send strong signals to conservative voters that they are taking a hard line on illegal drugs) has distorted many areas of useful research. For example he argued [in Nature](http://www.nature.com/nrn/journal/v14/n8/full/nrn3530.html) that:

> An important and unfortunate outcome of the controls placed on these and other psychoactive drugs is that they make research into their mechanisms of action and potential therapeutic uses — for example, in depression and post-traumatic stress disorder — difficult and in many cases almost impossible.

Which is another way of saying that government has strongly influenced what sort of research gets done. In other words, when legislation makes research hard and government is unlikely to want to pay for research that disagrees with their stated policy, then the agenda for researchers can be tightly restricted.

**Summary**

When government doesn't pay for all the work done by scientists there is clearly scope for many to do things government doesn't like. Even this, though, is hard when the laws put barriers to certain types of research. The more subtle idea of *[policy driven evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_evidence_making)* also causes bias.

Government typically has control of the majority of research funding. There are certainly instances when it uses this control and even legal and legislative means to influence the research agenda sometimes in ways that are not driven by a disinterested scientific agenda. This demonstrates bias. How big or *significant* this is to science as a whole is an open question, but it clearly exists.

Comment: This reads as a good essay, putting forward an opinion by giving examples, but does it really demonstrate that the governments' (occasional?) attempts to sway research work? Do scientists tend to move to balance (or even overreact) against such attempts? Do the deliberate efforts to have independent groups control the allocations of funds, within the budget provided by government help? (I am not naively suggesting they necessarily do.) Basically, is there systematic evidence rather than anecdotes?

Comment: "probably could never have expected government funding for research leading to this conclusion" <- begs the question. Also raises the issue of whether the conclusions are funded or the investigations into the questions. Ideally, I do NOT want my government to fund studies into Astrology, but they should never suppress any studies' findings, even if they find it works.

Comment: Completely agree with @Oddthinking's points.

Comment: @Oddthinking I hoped I had showed that there are some cases where government action had strongly influenced the research agenda. I wasn't trying to be systematic as I think the problem exists but isn't pervasive. Also how do you distinguish *complicit* behaviour by scientists who volunteer to support the government agenda because they think it will improve their chances of getting grants. I will see whether more extensive examples are demonstrable (I know they exist but my experience needs independent references).

Answer (score -6):

What constitutes bias? How might be go about finding whether there's bias?

If someone wants to do health research in the US then it's important for scientists to qualify either for industry funding or NIH grants. 
For this question it doesn't make sense to look at bias caused by industry funding.

If those people who get grants don't find the truth but something else you could call the bias due to grant seeking government indused bias.

We have to therefore ask ourselves, whether such systematic biases exist in science or whether the scientific community manages to kill those biases.
Before editing the original questions contained the assumption that the scientific process leads to truth. I therefore consider that to be a fair test of whether bias exists.

The Journal of Personality and Social Psychology published a paper called "[Feeling the Future: Experimental Evidence for Anomalous
Retroactive Influences on Cognition and Affect](http://dbem.ws/FeelingFuture.pdf)" by Daryl Bem in 2011 because the paper followed provided evidence for precognition that is as strong as the evidence in an average paper in the journal.

You don't need to be right to get a result published in academia. Precognition goes against the scientific consensus and therefore the paper got critized. A lot of papers who have similar evidence for the claims that they are making however don't go against the scientific consensus and therefore don't get critisied.

Breakthrough findings in basic cancer research seem to have a replication [rate of 11%](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v483/n7391/full/483531a.html).

In a famous peer reviewed article titled ["Why Most Published Research Findings Are False"](http://www.plosmedicine.org/article/info:doi/10.1371/journal.pmed.0020124) John Ioannnidis comes to the conclusion:

> Moreover, for many current scientific fields, claimed research findings may often be simply accurate measures of the prevailing bias."

Both cancer research and psychology are fields where it's easy to relicate experiments and make predictions about the outcome of experiments.
Climate Research is a field where a lot of researchers think that successfully predicting the past with their model is as good as predicting the future. It therefore plausible that Climate Research isn't much better than cancer research or psychology at correcting against bias.

In addition to small scale grants, sometimes researchers also want to get the government to pay for something that's more expansive.
As one example biologists wanted 3 billion dollar to sequence the human genome. If you would ask an average well educated person about the percentage of the human DNA that got sequenced I would guess that most people without a background in biology would say 100%.
In reality the number is something like 92%. 
Those biologists had an incentive to show the general public that the 3 billion dollar were well spent money. They profit if the public believes that they actually archived more than they achieved.

Similarly if you read the [fine print](http://www.ipcc.ch/pdf/assessment-report/ar4/wg1/ar4-uncertaintyguidancenote.pdf) of the [IPCC report](http://www.ipcc.ch/publications_and_data/ar4/syr/en/spms2.html), the report concludes that "net effect of human activities since 1750 has been one of warming" is a claim with "At least 9 out of 10 chance of being correct".
In the public discourse it's hard to tell people that a 9/10 of being true should motivate people to reduce emissions. Many people can't handle it intellectually that a claim isn't either true or false but can be 90% true. As a result a lot of the public communication is targeted at getting people to believe that the claim has a 10/10 chance of being true. That what people do who want to achieve the politically goal of lowering emissions.

It's problematic because if we had models that would 100% accurately predict what the climate does geoengieering would probably outperform cutting emissions. 
Explaining to the public that a model is good enough to advocate cutting emissions but not good enough for geoengieering is hard. It's politics.

Comment: You need to cite a reference for your first paragraph.  That appears to be your opinion as written.  I think you also need to remove your opinions on why things are the way they are where they are not supported by refrenced studies.  These seem to be the core of your answer but maybe that is just how I am reading it.

Comment: There is a huge unsupported claim in this answer: "The US government gets usually run by people who went to Yale or Harvard." Somehow, there seems to be a bias sneaking through in this answer itself.

Comment: @Christian, It would seem that only a few presidents went to either of those institutions. - Harvard University: John Adams, John Quincy Adams, Theodore Roosevelt, Franklin D. Roosevelt, John F. Kennedy.

Yale University: William Howard Taft, George H. W. Bush, George W. Bush.

Comment: This answer contains a lot of material - and yet really doesn't address the question. It might even be read as containing a lot of stuff you just wanted to get off your chest. Perhaps with some restructuring, stripping out the bits that don't directly address the question and the bits that are unsupported by your references, there's a good answer hiding in here. I'd like to see that good answer brought out.

Comment: Also, of the current senators in office, 7 went to Harvard and 6 went to Yale, of those, only 1 is a republican. I wonder where this meme came from?

Comment: @woodchipsit I removed the first paragraph with that claim as it was a response to a part of the question that's now removed.

Comment: Sorry, this seems to be a collection of personal opinions and cherry picking of examples.

Comment: @Chad, Christian: Sorry, I cleaned up the question, and I obviously overlapped with Christian, so his quotes of the question were no longer relevant.

Comment: @Sklivvz: I'm not cherry picking. With the IPCC I'm citing the most respected source on climate change. With Ioannidis I'm also citing the most respected authority on the topic. Citing a big pharma VP for the quality of basic cancer research also seems to be fair. The Bem episode also isn't an obscure example but a story where I would expect that a lot of Skeptics readers already know the story. I could also speak about Voodoo Neuroscience, NASA discovery that supposedly expands our definition of life or supposedly superfast neutriones. There're plenty examples.

Comment: It's still cherry picking... Find studies to support your view. We already told you that showing examples of scientists being wrong does not answer the question.

Comment: For the "Why Most Published Research Findings Are False" paper by John Ioannnidis, see [link]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBNeuG10-ac&feature=plcp - A scientific explanation of this.

Comment: @Sklivvz "Is there any evidence that some notable research has been biased in the findings or peer review due to government influence?" - the answer addresses this with firm "yes", with evidence. The question is not whether ALL research is biased, but if some bias exists. In order to prove that it does, you need just a couple of examples, which is what this answer does.