# Did the National Rifle Association (NRA) block research into statistics related to gun control?

Tags: united-states, politics, guns

About 30,000 Americans die every year from gun-related deaths (a number likely to exceed those dying from automobile-related accidents very soon if trends continue). About 1 in 3 of those are homicides and the remainder suicides. Together this totals more than 300,000 since the world Trade Centre attacks.

A recent editorial in the journal [JAMA Internal Medicine](http://archinte.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=1661391) claimed that the NRA had used its legislative clout to block public funding for research to find out what measures might reduce the death rate. In their words (but my highlights):

> Today, with almost no funding for firearm violence research, there are almost no researchers. Counting all academic disciplines together, no more than a dozen active, experienced investigators in the United States have focused their careers primarily on firearm violence. Only 2 are physicians. Only 1 has evaluated the effectiveness of an assault weapons ban.
>
> Why did this happen? In the early 1990s, scientists were producing evidence that might have been used to reform the nation’s firearm policies. **To those whose interests were threatened by such reforms, it made perfect sense to choke off the production of the evidence. This effort was led by Congressman Jay Dickey, self-described “point person for the NRA.” It succeeded**. When rates of firearm violence were at historic highs and appeared to be increasing, the government abandoned its commitment to understanding the problem and devising evidence-based solutions.

Given the poverty of good statistics on the topic and the relevance of such statistics for policy (see the difficulty of finding good statistics in this question: [Is gun control effective?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/976/is-gun-control-effective) ) , this seems strange. But is it true? Did the NRA successfully lobby to block research funding related to gun control and gun violence?

Comment: It might, in this context, be helpful to distinguish between "research" and "manipulation of statistics to further a political agenda".

Comment: There appears to be a misprint in the question, which asks if "the NRA had used its legislative clout to block **any** public funding for such research", but the original source doesn't say that, it only states that **most** public funding was blocked. Anyone object if I edit?

Comment: @DJClayworth no problem.

Comment: So,.what, now the question is asking "Has the NRA had any influence at all on the level of funding for research regarding gun safety"? This edit makes the question vague, ambiguous, and trivial.

Comment: The flavor in the recent re edit is wrong now, USA deaths from cars are exceeded by guns now in America, due to the continuing trend of research making things better at what they are supposed to do https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/injury.htm

Comment: "Most countries facing a public health threat of this magnitude would have spent" there is a list of countries with a greater death rate that spend less government money on research, Mexico, South Africa, most of South America. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_firearm-related_death_rate

Comment: "*About 1 in 3 of those are homicides and the remainder suicides.*" -> Is the number of accidents negligeable ?

Comment: @Evargalo I recall a statistic of about 500 deaths per year that the police listed as accidental (guns going off while cleaning, being dropped, etc.). So around 2%. It's a matter of opinion whether that is negligible.

Comment: @Evargalo Depends what you count as "negligible". accidental deaths are between 500-1,000 in the USA (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_violence_in_the_United_States)) which is negligible compared to total gun deaths but a lot compared to, for example, the *total* rate of gun deaths in the UK even adjusted for the US population.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the figures. I conclude that the formulation I quoted from the question is reasonnable.

Comment: Do you have a source for the 300,000 statistics and the 1:3 homicides, remainder suicides you stated at the beginning?

Comment: @ChrisRogers Some more recent stats illustrating that ratio and other relevant numbers [are compiled by the BBC here.](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-41488081)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

**Yes they did.**

The [Tiahrt amendment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd_Tiahrt#Tiahrt_Amendment) prevents firearms data from being released to anyone other than law enforcement - including gun ownership statistics and many gun-related crime statistics. This effectively prevents most academic research into gun ownership, gun crime, gun violence and even some gun accidents, by denying researchers access to the necessary raw data. The ban applies to all research, public and private, except law enforcement (who are ill-equipped or not mandated to carry out academic research). The amendment was promoted heavily by the NRA who made large campaign contributions specifically to legislators who supported the ban. They also arranged for the passage of the [Dickey Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickey_Amendment_(1996)) which [prevents the Centre for Disease Control spending any money at all on research "that might advocate or promote gun control"](http://www.livescience.com/26253-government-stifled-gun-research.html) (the CDC is tasked with research into other non-disease causes of death and injury such as traffic and domestic accident). The restriction was later extended to other publicly funded bodies. The definition of what might "advocate or promote gun control" was left deliberately vague, and given the possibility of criminal prosecution if your research was found to do so, virtually everyone abandoned the area of research. A small amount of research has continued despite the restrictions.

References:

- [Slate Magazine](http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/science/2012/12/gun_violence_research_nra_and_congress_blocked_gun_control_studies_at_cdc.html)
- [Live Science](http://www.livescience.com/26253-government-stifled-gun-research.html)
- [Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/01/10/us-usa-guns-scientists-idUSBRE90915F20130110)
- [USA Today](http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2013/01/16/obama-gun-research-violence/1840367/)
- [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/robwaters/2012/12/17/gun-violence-americas-secret-health-crisis/)

Comment: Who is "they"? The NRA didn't block research, they just lobbied for the amendment.

Comment: The limitation on the ATF's ability to respond to Freedom of Information Act request was adopted 13 February 2003.  The Taihrt amendment was 16 July 2003.  http://prtl-sitea-maigs.nyc.gov/html/federal/history_tiahrt.shtml

Comment: The OP is referring to an earlier event in 1996, which is:  "But in 1996...the House of Representatives removed $2.6 million from the CDC's budget—precisely the amount the agency had spent on firearm injury research the previous year. Funding was restored in joint conference committee, but the money was earmarked for traumatic brain injury. The effect was sharply reduced support for firearm injury research." http://jama.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=1487470

Comment: It's worth noting that the article's summary of the [Dickey Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickey_Amendment_(1996)) seems inaccurate on its face (the language of the amendment doesn't include anything equivalent to the "might" that the article uses - it bans gun control advocacy, not some ill-specified set of things that "might" promote gun control). But even if the characterisation given in the article were true it would still not come close to banning the CDC from *"spending any money at all on research into firearms death and injury"* as you claim.

Comment: You fail to quote *anything* from your alleged sources to support your claim. -1

Comment: @MarkAmery from reading other articles, it seems that the Dickey Amendment's wording only prevents outright advocacy, but that the practical effect has been enough of a chilling effect to prevent research altogether, as researchers don't want to get into the field only to discover that they have no way of getting funding (for example).

Comment: @BenBarden Maybe. Or maybe such genuine *research* into gun control measures was never being done, and the conservative narrative (in which the Dickey Amendment was a necessary tool to prevent funding meant for research from being diverted into advocacy by left-leaning civil servants) is an entirely fair one. I don't know, but I'd need to see a detailed examination of what sort and number of studies were being conducted before and after the ban in order to be persuaded either way - not just a detail-free retelling of one side or the other's favoured political narrative.

Comment: The CDC carried out extensive research into gun injuries and prevention before the Tiahrt amendment, but it all stopped afterwards. Check the links in the answer.

Comment: The claim was that ALL researched was blocked. An answer which only shows that federal research was blocked is irrelevant. And you provide no citation giving the language of this alleged threat of criminal prosecution.

Comment: @Acccumulation I did edit the answer to make it slightly clearer. But if you read the links they are absolutely clear. The Tiahrt amendment prevents firearms data from being released to **anybody who is not law enforcement**. Private, public, whatever. They cannot get access to the raw data.

Comment: The Tiahrt amendment prohibits **ATF firearms trace** data from being released. It is not a blanket ban on firearms data being released, and does not prohibit private or public agencies from doing research, it just blocks **one potential source of data**.

Comment: @Acccumulation maybe you would like to explain what other data is allowed to be released, and how useful that other data would be to researchers.

Comment: I'm not going to list every potential source of data. Saying you can't do research on firearms without the ATF firearms trace database is like saying that you can't do research on traffic fatalities without having the DMV's database linking license plates to owners. The overwhelming impression I get is that you are being deliberately dishonest.

Comment: You could try naming one useful source of data. But the research community believes that the ATF Firearms Trace database is absolutely the most important and significant source of data, and it's unavailability cripples firearms research.  As for accusing me of dishonesty, you might want to think about whether that is an "uncivil tone".

Comment: This beefy pdf seems like counter evidence http://www.bjs.gov/content/pub/pdf/fv9311.pdf

Comment: There is also this from the CDC after 2004 too, https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/mm6018a1.htm

Comment: @DJClayworth forgot to tag you, this chocolate bar in front of me is absolutely the most important and significant source of protein

Comment: @DJClayworth your edit underlines the point accumulation made, how much is 'A small amount of research'? What amount of research from the CDC would you consider to sufficient to disprove your claim?

Comment: @daniel Anything other than a small amount.

Comment: @DJClayworth x researchers, y publications, z direct funding for research on firearm violence?

Comment: Yes, any of those where x, y and z are small. But seriously, if you know the values of x, y or z then write an answer saying "The amount of research wasn't affected because it was x1 before and it was x2 after, and that isn't much difference". Then we can look at the answer and decide if it's a good one.

Comment: @DJClayworth your answer is applying absolute wording where there is none in reality. The above comments are the best 'no true Scotsman' example I've seen, 'try naming one useful source of data.' 'Here's a link to one, a second from the CDC' that's not true data'

Comment: I'm fully aware and even say that small amounts of research are still published. I'm happy to admit that two papers is a 'small' amount of research. I'm not even sure what you are disagreeing with me about.

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm disagreeing with you you about "Did the National Rifle Association (NRA) block research into statistics related to gun control? Yes they did" because its not absolute, the republicans without NRA funds would have drawn a line somehwere on the deweaponizing, the current status is that no private research is blocked, state government orgs were not blocked, federal orgs such as the CDC lost some funding but were never blocked from studying gun control, just from promoting it.

Comment: The new recent news from congress shows this by keeping the old wording and clarifying it. https://politics.myajc.com/blog/politics/cdc-can-conduct-gun-violence-research-congress-says/a2PhJAoij2b5JZstUyv9ZJ/

Comment: @daniel There is a LONG discussion on Accumulation's answer that addresses this, going over all the same ground. But the short answer is that Yes, the Tiahrt amendment DOES block access to firearms data by all sources, public and private (everyone except law enforcement). If you want to contribute to that discussion there is a link to chat in the comments. But I'm not going to go over all the same ground again.

Comment: @DJClayworth it's a long discussion that you didnt budge on, that point that the 'NRA has no authority to pass laws' is worth a bolded asterisk in your answer, also the point that it's not all data, but a small amount of data used by law enforcement.

Comment: You've said nothing new so I'm not going to argue with you.

Comment: @daniel : I'm not even sure what you are trying to prove. The OP's question is "*Did the National Rifle Association (NRA) block research into statistics related to gun control?*", and this answer "*Yes they did.*" is well documented. NRA did put a lot of effort in blocking such research, and their lobbying has been successful as shown by the Tiahrt amendment. The fact that some data might still be accessible and that some research is still done doesn't disprove NRA's actions.

Comment: @Evargalo the Secretary of Health and Human Services has stated the CDC has the authority to conduct research on the causes of gun violence, I'll re write the question to fit this answer: Did the NRA, along with most Republicans, block some public research into statistics related to (and likely advocating for) gun control for a time? Yes they did.

Comment: And by 'block' I mean 'remove funding and have a chilling effect on', not block as in ban or make illegal

Answer (score 23):

The specific legislation you're interested is the [Tiahrt Amendment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd_Tiahrt#Tiahrt_Amendment). It is quite contentious because it was designed to block a lot of data collected by the ATF from being used academically. The motivation behind this is that past releases of such information were used for political purposes rather than objective academic or scientific pursuits.

The worry from groups who support the right to keep and bear arms is that showing "firearms correlate to X" would lead to further gun control legislation. Knowing something scientifically is good, using that knowledge to justify political goals is where it gets contentious.

The original question may help highlight these concerns. A journal about internal medicine has a clear interest in knowing more about firearm injuries and how to treat. Should a group of medical experts be advising for gun control or solely focused on the clinical treatment and care of firearm injuries?

Comment: I think the pointer to the Tihart Amendment is an excellent reference. However, you go on to explain the motivation of the Tihart Amendment and the worries of (unnamed) groups, without any references to support them. Please add references.

Comment: I think it is also worth making the distinction that the NRA has no authority to pass laws. It is the Congress that blocked the research. This answer doesn't demonstrate that Congress was influenced by the NRA, which is required to answer the question in the title.

Comment: I'm working to dig up sources. Since the original question cited JAMA, a source who seems to object to the Tihart Amendment, I think it is important to cite and quote sources which support it. We're talking about a giant piece of American law, policy, and culture I do not think a simple yes/no answer is sufficient to address the issue.

Comment: @Freiheit: The data in question would have more propaganda value than research value, given that it would be subject to substantial but unquantifiable selection biases. Most firearm crimes do not result in a trace of the weapon involved, and many firearms are traced without ever having been used to commit crimes; the way many "researchers" use firearm-trace statistics, however, would be equivalent to using the (hypothetical) fact that black motorists in some area are pulled over more often than white motorists to suggest that black people in that are less law-abiding than white people.

Comment: @Freiheit: The danger actually goes beyond the propaganda value of the false claims. Those involved in deciding which firearms should be traced should base their decisions upon the usefulness of information that would be gleaned thereby, not upon the statistical picture that their decisions would paint. If certain people want a certain type of firearm to show up disproportionately in traces, they could easily make that happen regardless of the extent to which such firearms are actually used in crime. Whether or not people *do* that is unclear, but they would certainly have the power.

Answer (score 14):

**Simple answer - Yes** , NRA helped in blocking research associated with gun violence and statistics associated with it , by a major piece of legislation called as "**[Dickey Amendment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickey_Amendment_(1996))**" which was passed in the year 1996 and was prominently lobbied by NRA , which stopped CDC from spending money into research associated with gun violence . The bill is named after co-sponsor of the bill - [Jay Dickey](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jay_Dickey) , a Republican congressman from Arkansas. According to the Dickey amendment-

> None of the funds made available for injury prevention and control at
>   the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) may be used to
>   advocate or promote gun control.

Link: [Why So Few Scientists Are Studying the Causes of Gun Violence](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/cdc-still-cant-study-causes-gun-violence-180955884/?no-ist) (Smithsonian.com, 13 Jul 2015)

But NRA went even a step further , by passing legislation to stop **Bureau of Arms , Tobacco and Firearms** to keep all the firearms and other records associated with it in form of electronic database (so even by mistake government cannot release any kind of statistics).

Links: [How the N.R.A. Keeps Federal Gun Regulators in Check](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/02/22/us/politics/trump-atf-nra.html) (NY Times, 22 Feb 2018)
[NRA TV: inside the channel activists are urging Apple and Amazon to axe](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2018/feb/28/nratv-gun-tv-channel-apple-amazon-google)  (The Guardian, 1 Mar 2018)

This episode of the last week tonight from John Oliver is a must see when it comes to NRA - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=_ECYMvjU52E

Answer (score 2):

To claim that *no* gun research is allowed with *public* money is imprecise at best, and a lie at worst. No *advocacy* of gun control is allowed with *federal* money. The Dickey Amendment states: "none of the funds made available for injury prevention and control at the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention may be used to advocate or promote gun control." So, this applies to: 1. the CDC 2. spending money for injury prevention 3. for advocating gun control.

Not *everything* gun related is off-limits for federal spending; otherwise how would the FBI know that "[Firearms were used in 71.5 percent of the nation’s murders, 40.8 percent of robberies, and 24.2 percent of aggravated assaults](https://www.fbi.gov/news/stories/latest-crime-statistics-released)"? State governments are free to spend their money on gun research: "[California's response to the federal funding blockade was a budget rider last year establishing the Firearm Violence Research Center at UC Davis and funding it with a five-year grant of $5 million.](http://www.latimes.com/business/hiltzik/la-fi-hiltzik-wintemute-20170714-story.html)" And your quote from JAMA (who, by the way, has been at the forefront at politicizing the gun issue and therefore instigating NRA action) goes beyond talking about federal or even state funding, and claims there is a lack of funding *at all*.

From the LA Times article:

> The vacuum in federally funded gun violence research dates to 1996, when Congress passed a measure by then-Rep. Jay Dickey (R-Ark.), a cat’s-paw of the National Rifle Assn., forbidding the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention to spend any funds “to advocate or promote gun control.”
>
> A succession of pusillanimous CDC directors decided that the safest course bureaucratically was simply to spend nothing at all on gun violence research — even when they were specifically ordered to reenter the field by President Obama, following the Sandy Hook Elementary massacre in 2012.

So the NRA did help pass legislation that has created a hostile environment for spending money on gun research, and this legislation has influenced bureacrats in deciding to limit research, but it did not *ban* reaserch.

Several other answers have mentioned the Tiahrt Amendment. @DJClayworth phrases it as "prevents firearms data from being released to anyone other than law enforcement - including gun ownership statistics and many gun-related crime statistics." However, the wikipedia page on it says that it "prohibits the National Tracing Center of the Bureau of Alcohol, Tobacco, Firearms and Explosives (ATF) from releasing information from its firearms trace database to anyone other than a law enforcement agency or prosecutor in connection with a criminal investigation." According to https://www.atf.gov/firearms/national-tracing-center "Firearms tracing is the systematic tracking of the movement of a firearms recovered by law enforcement officials from its first sale by the manufacturer or importer through the distribution chain (wholesaler/retailer) to the first retail purchaser. Comprehensive firearms tracing is the routine tracing of every crime gun recovered within a geographic area or specific law enforcement jurisdiction." That doesn't sound to me like "gun-related crime statistics", except in the broadest sense. That sounds to me like gun dealers are required to register with the ATF, and the ATF is prohibited from sharing the information they provide with researchers. This is data that people have been required by law to provide to the ATF, and there are valid privacy concerns. This is not public information that's being withheld. The DMV keeps track of who owns what car; should that be freely available to researchers?

Comment: Nobody is claiming that the ban applies to crime statistics.

Comment: You are trying to hide behind an irrelevant technicality. Threatening to prosecute researchers who are found to have "promoted gun control" without defining what that means is undoubtedly intended to prevent any research. It's the same as if someone says "if you go into that room I might kill you". Technically it isn't a ban on entering the room, but the reality is nobody will go in.

Comment: @DJClayworth  yea nobody is claiming a ban... except the current answer reads "These bans cover all research..."

Comment: To be specific only law enforcement has access to the raw data, so they can compile crime statistics. Literally everybody else is not allowed access to the statistics.

Comment: @DJClayworth "Nobody is claiming that the ban applies to crime statistics." Crime statistics is research. "You are trying to hide behind an irrelevant technicality. " Your tone is quite uncivil, and you are unclear what that "technicality" is. "Threatening to prosecute researchers who are found to have 'promoted gun control' without defining what that means" You provide no cite for that. And I clearly acknowledged that " NRA did help pass legislation that has created a hostile environment". " is undoubtedly intended to prevent any research." No, that is not undoubtedly the intent.

Comment: One key feature of research is that you don't always know the result you will get. So if the CDC did research that concluded that restrictions on guns were an effective way to limit the harms from guns would that count as advocacy? It looks to me as though the law limits any research that might possibly result in that outcome.

Comment: @matt_black "Advocacy" means taking a position. It doesn't mean "producing data".

Comment: @Acccumulation The technicality is that you are saying there is no "ban" because a small amount of research is still allowed despite the severe obstacles imposed. (Incidentally, you are the person talking about a "ban" the question is about "blocking" research, which certainly happened. I'm sorry you find my tone uncivil. Others seem to find it OK, based on the upvotes. And if you don't think that the purpose of the NRA is to block all research, then you are clearly in a minority.

Comment: @Acccumulation But if I publicise the research (say by writing for a newspaper) that says guns control works is that advocacy? What if publishing the result of the research in the scientific literature counts as "publicising", is that advocacy? Scientific results are not neutral.

Comment: @Acccumulation You may think that there is "Advocacy" only when someone takes a position. But the NRA would disagree with you. The trigger for these amendments was  when "[agency-funded research had revealed that residents of homes with guns had a higher likelihood of violent death in the home](https://www.livescience.com/26253-government-stifled-gun-research.html).". That's just publishing simple facts. But it's exactly that kind of research that the NRA sought to block.

Comment: @Acccumulation Thank you for making your edit, which entirely backs up my point that the Tiahrt amendment prevents firearms data from being released to anyone other than law enforcement or prosecutors. Your speculation that this might be to protect the privacy of gun dealers is precisely that -speculation. It's also ill-founded speculation. Medical data is even more private, yet it is regularly released to academics to conduct research, and there are conditions, such as anonymization, that take care of the privacy issues. Without doubt the same could be applied to firearms trace data.

Comment: @DJClayworth No, it prevents a *specific set* of data from being released.It is getting more and more difficult to believe you are acting in good faith. The question is whether *all* research is banned, not whether the government hasn't thrown open all their databases for researchers. I stated the *fact* that privacy concerns exist, I did not *speculate* as to whether that was the motive. Bringing up medical records is just a bunch of whatsaboutism.

Comment: @DJClayworth "The technicality is that you are saying there is no "ban" because a small amount of research is still allowed despite the severe obstacles imposed." That's not a "technicality", that's the actual answer. The question asks whether ALL research is blocked. The answer is "no". Your argumentum ad populum aside, it's rather rude to accuse someone of a "technicality" for answering the question AS ASKED, and *pointing out in their own answer* that there still is a hostile environment for research.

Comment: @DJClayworth "(Incidentally, you are the person talking about a "ban" the question is about "blocking" research, which certainly happened." The question specifically asks about "block **any** public funding". My bolding. Not block *some* research. "Block any public funding" means ban. "And if you don't think that the purpose of the NRA is to block all research, then you are clearly in a minority" Truth is not a democracy. And the question doesn't ask about "the purpose of the NRA". More bad faith from you.

Comment: The reason your answer is unpopular is that it goes on and on about the tiny amount of research not blocked by the NRA sponsored amendments, while other answers focus on the huge amount of research they succeeded in blocking. Your answer may be factually correct but it misses the point.

Comment: @DJClayworth My answer focuses on the research that isn't blocked, because *that's the answer*. If someone were to ask whether every American who fought in WWII is dead, I would answer "no", and I would base that on the 660k who are alive, not on the 15m who aren't. *That's how the word "all" works*. **You** are the one missing the point, not me. Naming research after research that has been blocked does NOTHING to answer the question, which is whether ALL research has been blocked. Your insistence on pretending otherwise is tiresome.

Comment: That's like answering a question asking if "Joe Smith is a serial killer who killed twenty people" by saying "No that's absolutely false and a despicable lie - he only killed 19 people". "Any" is clearly a misprint in the question, as the original sources don't make that claim. I suggested an edit.

Comment: Edit approved by the OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74900/discussion-between-acccumulation-and-djclayworth).

Answer (score -6):

**No, they didn't**

The [NRA is a civil rights organization](http://home.nra.org), and isn't capable of blocking federal research funding related to gun violence and gun control. That is the job of Congress.

Congress passed the [1996 Omnibus Consolidated Appropriations Bill](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/PLAW-104publ208/pdf/PLAW-104publ208.pdf), which contains the following language:

> none of the funds made available for injury prevention and control at the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention may be used to advocate or promote gun control

This amendment was added by U.S. House Representative Jay Dickey (R-AR) and was approved by 104th Congress. The [American Psychology Association](http://www.apa.org/science/about/psa/2013/02/gun-violence.aspx), that was against the Dickey Amendment admits:

> **this language did not explicitly ban research on gun violence**. However, Congress also took $2.6 million from the CDC’s budget — the amount the CDC had invested in firearm injury research the previous year —and earmarked the funds for prevention of traumatic brain injury.

From the CDC themselves, they note the Dickey Amendment **does not block research/funding** related to gun control/gun violence.

> AR-13: Prohibition on Use of CDC Funds for Certain Gun Control Activities
>   The Departments of Labor, Health and Human Services, and Education, and Related Agencies Appropriations Act specifies that: "None of the funds made available for injury prevention and control at the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention may be used to advocate or promote gun control."
>
> Anti-Lobbying Act requirements prohibit lobbying Congress with appropriated Federal monies. **Specifically, this Act prohibits the use of Federal funds for direct or indirect communications intended or designed to influence a member of Congress with regard to specific Federal legislation.** This prohibition includes the funding and assistance of public grassroots campaigns intended or designed to influence members of Congress with regard to specific legislation or appropriation by Congress.
>
> In addition to the restrictions in the Anti-Lobbying Act, CDC interprets the language in the CDC's Appropriations Act to mean that **CDC's funds may not be spent on political action or other activities designed to affect the passage of specific Federal, State, or local legislation intended to restrict or control the purchase or use of firearms.**

Comment: The NRA became concerned when a New England Journal of Medicine (NEJM) published an article, “Gun ownership as a risk factor for homicide in the home,” funded by the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC). The study found that keeping a gun in the home was strongly and independently associated with an increased risk of homicide (similar to how unmarried mothers put [themselves and kids at greater risk](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/21922/does-getting-married-prevent-violence-against-women-and-children/21957#21957)

Comment: Perhaps it isn't obvious, but I never assumed the NRA had legislative powers. The intent of the question, which should be clear from the context, was to ask if NRA lobbying and action was instrumental in influencing congress to pass such laws.

Comment: @Matt_black, then the question should be reworded. From the context of the quote of the claim, it appears that Jay Dicky was "successfully at blocking research related to gun violence, not the NRA." Additionally, the American Psychology Association that was originally against the Dicky amendment wrote, "**language did not explicitly ban research on gun violence**." Even the opponents admit that the "NRA" didn't succeed.

Comment: And before you say, "the cut/moved their funding for gun injury research," that assumes we should continually fund the same research each year.

Comment: @user1873 There's a difference between increasing/reducing a budget and removing it entirely in one go...

Comment: The Dickey Amendment cut funding. But the Tiahrt Amendment made it illegal for the CDC to research gun deaths.

Comment: Nonsense. If you make it criminal to come to a possible objective conclusion in research, then you've criminalized the research. It's not research if you already know the conclusions, and you can't avoid the conclusions up front if you are conducting objective research where you can't control the outcome. And when a legislator's desired outcome determines whether a conclusion is "advocacy" or not, that's banning the research is exactly what is happening.

Answer (score -9):

You give the [National Rifle Association](http://nra.org) too much credit.

For the rest of the story, please see [The History of Public Health Gun Control](https://drgo.us/?p=1134), a series in three parts, and the followup [DRGO's 1996 Congressional Testimony: Defunding Gun Control Politics at the CDC](https://drgo.us/?p=2919) which provides the actual transcript. They're published by [Doctors for Responsible Gun Ownership](http://drgo.us), a project of the [Second Amendment Foundation](http://saf.org).

**Summary:**

1. The National Rifle Association informed the House of Representatives Appropriation Committee in 1996 about the CDC’s misuse of authority and federal funds which were based on bad science through a panel of experts.

   > The radical deviation of public health research on guns from mainstream criminology research attracted the attention of the National Rifle Association, a citizen-based group of American gun owners.  These observers were rightfully concerned not only about the misuse of science to advance a political agenda of gun control, but also about the spending of millions of dollars of taxpayer money to do it.  The NRA asked Congress to address the problem.  In March 1996 I was one of three medical doctors and a criminologist who testified before the House of Representatives Appropriation Committee.  We informed the committee of the CDC’s misuse of its authority and of federal funds to advance a plainly political agenda of gun control based on bad science.
2. The National Rifle Association spends millions of dollars and many hours of volunteers’ time on education to public about firearm safety and legal use.

   > Running through most of these articles is a common thread that because of Congress’s mandate that federal tax money not be used to fund gun control advocacy, there is a shortage of research on ways to reduce “gun violence.”  They routinely demonize the National Rifle Association, accusing them of suppressing research that would help us find a solution to misuse of firearms. Former CDC official Dr. Mark Rosenberg even accused the NRA in a supposedly straight news piece of “terrorizing the CDC and the research community.” These biased journalists ignore the fact that the NRA spends millions of dollars and many hours of volunteers’ time in educating the public about firearm safety and legal use.

Comment: Please quote what they say and summarise it. Asking us to read thousands of words just to find out what your argument is is too much.

Comment: I expect intellectual dishonesty from NRA proponents, and I'm not disappointed. Your second point is like saying that the tobacco industry's really made of good guys because they tell people how to *safely* smoke cigarettes so they don't need the evil nasty government telling them what to sell.

Comment: But of course I'm sure an entity with a noble name like the Second Amendment Foundation could not possibly be biased in favour of the NRA in any way, but instead exhibit only the most rigorous standards of neutrality and objectivity.

Comment: #1 sounds like a scientist who didn't think the CDC should be spending money on doing any gun-related research. #2 seems to be saying that because the NRA spends money on gun education, that means they support research on reducing gun violence. Both sound lame.

Comment: "The National Rifle Association informed the House of Representatives Appropriation Committee in 1996 about the CDC’s misuse of authority and federal funds which were based on bad science". Because obviously the NRA is better suited to judge what is good science than the CDC. Down vote.